# Один сайт - два VPS

Tags: apache, ubuntu

ОС Ubuntu 12.04, apache

**Цель:** чтобы 2 сервера(VPS) обслуживали один сайт. Т.е. чтобы у них была общая база, и если один сервер ляжет, оставался второй который держит сайт. (не обязательно выносить базу на отдельный сервер)

Насколько я понял, есть несколько возможностей это реализовать:

1. Чтобы сервера грузились одинаково(50/50 разделяли нагрузку)
2. Чтобы работал один, и когда он будет падать, работал второй

Подскажите пожалуйста, в какую сторону двигаться, и какой из способов выбрать. Либо может я заблуждаюсь, и есть третий способ.

P.S. Надеюсь ничего страшного, что к домену прикручен сертификат ssl, он будет работать на разных серверах?

Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1):

товарищь skykub написал что-то монструозное на основе солярки. можно сделать все проще

берешь 3 vps-ки, из одной делаешь фронтенд с nginx-ом, который будет проксировать бекенды. домен+ssl прикручиваешь к фронтенду. на бекендах поднимаешь веб-сервера, которые будут слушать запросы с фронтенда. на одном из бекендов будет мастер база, на другом слейв в режиме хотстендбай. пока все хорошо фронтенд пропускает через себя запросы на бекенды. веб-сервера на бекендах отвечают поочереди, вместе обращаются к одной базе, которая мастер. когда ломается один из бекендов. то на фронтенде отключаем проксирование на него, делаем из слейва мастер базу, если упал бекенд с текущим мастером. если упал бекенд со слейвом, просто поднимаем его. когда все заработает на фронтенде опять пускаем нагрузку на оба сервера. сделать это полностью автоматически можно, но сложно. простых решений в стиле накатил что-то, скопипастил конфиги где-то и все работает как часы, к сожалению, пока нету. хотя возможно кто-то что-то делает в этом направлении.

Comment: Я и описывал именно атоматически переезжающий с ноды на ноду кластер. Ручками можно и еще проще сделать, но задача-то именно так и поставлена. И, кстати, не обязательно солярка, можно и AIX ;) (ну если есть парочка ibm). А с разделением нагрузки - это вообще сервер реального времени. Там еще сложнее.

Comment: Кластер - это кластер (Более одного сервера, работающих параллельно.) Не путайте понятия, вам нужно "облако" !

Answer (score 0):

Вы чтото слишком все усложняете: [nginx Load Balance Example](http://wiki.nginx.org/LoadBalanceExample). Переходите в 21 век :)
Nginx умеет сам балансить нагрузку и соответсвенно в неработающую штуку ничего не пошлет.С базами -- все правильно описано, hot standby ваш выбор ([нануглить проблемы нету](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?146,171968,171968#msg-171968))

Если хочется именно 2 сервера, то тут либо хардварным путем решать (что тут не получится) либо с помощью [CARP](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/carp.html).

> The Common Address Redundancy Protocol (CARP) allows multiple hosts to share the same IP address. In some configurations, this may be used for availability or load balancing. Hosts may use separate IP addresses, as in the example provided here.

К сожалению сам не настраивал -- не на чем было :(

UPD: На хабре есть хорошее описание: [Отказоустойчивая система на базе репликации mySQL и сетевого протокола CARP](http://habrahabr.ru/post/185318/)

Answer (score -1):

> Чтобы работал один, и когда он будет падать, работал второй

1. Ставишь одинаковую систему (например солярку)
2. Ставишь кластер (например veritas)
3. Поднимаешь На одной ноде группу SQLgrp - там будет крутится база. Там же (в группе) примонтируешь внешний накопитель, где собственно и буде лежать база. Точка монтирования должна иметь место быть на обеих нодах
4. На другой ноде поднимаешь группу Apachegrp - там будет крутиться апач и иже с ним.там же примонтируешь внешний накопитель, где будут домашние директории юзеров, почтовые, ftp, www. Точка монтирования должна иметь место быть на обеих нодах

   > 

Дисковые накопители должны быть автономными, иначе при выходе из строя одной ноды на другую подмонтировать будет нечего. Юзеры и группы должны быть синхронизированы между нодами по ID (UID,GID) иначе возникнут конфликты прав при переезде с ноды на ноду.

ИМХО дорого, геморно и заслуживает внимания только при ооочень серьезных проектах.

Comment: > ИМХО дорого, геморно и заслуживает внимания только при ооочень серьезных проектах.конечно, если такие решения применять, то так. Только с тех пор как ваш дедушка был админом веб сильно подешевел в том числе кластерный.

Comment: Не нужно оскорблять. Мой дедушка бал машинистом паровоза. А на таких системах я работаю сейчас. Буквально вчера обслуживал двухнодовый кластер на PrimePower 650. И цены я знаю. Каков вопрос, таков и ответ

Comment: Где оскорбление ? Вы знаете цены на очень странное для таких целей оборудование, а знаете главную проблему которую реально сложно решить, если не имеешь подсеть в BGP ?  установка fallback в разные датацентры с переключением в пару минут. И тут никакие соляры и прочие изыски конца XX века не помогут. Помогают всякие центральные отказоустойчивые сервисы, но опять-же начинаешь зависеть от них. А они тоже падают.